# A problem with progressive percentage incrementation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have absolutely no clue if any of the terms I used in the title actually exist or make sense. I'm usually good at math (relatively) but I am facing this problem today that I just cannot solve.

John likes apples. He goes to the store and buys an apple for `$10.00`. The next day he goes to the store again, but surprisingly finds out that an apple now costs `$11.00`. On the third day John has paid `$12.10` for an apple. How much would John have to pay on day 51?

So I guess each subsequent day the price goes up by 10% but how can I calculate that progressive incrementation at day 51? Yeah of course I can sit down with the calculator and add that 50 times, but I guess there must be an actual mathematical solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: @vadim123 that was extremely useful, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On day $51$, he pays $10\times (\frac{11}{10})^{50}$ dollars.

Comment: Which means $1173.91$ dollars for a single apple. Tell me the name of the store : I must forbid my wife to go there !!! Cheers.